# Vue life cycle hooks as events (hook:beforeDestroy)

Tags: vue.js

How to use vue hooks-as-events syntax?

for example `this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy')`

I searched but could not find any references to it in the official docs. Is it deprecated?

Comment: [https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy)

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu the question is correct. its not in the docs. he is not referring to the hook but to the event-syntax.

Comment: I never said the question wasn't correct, nor have I voted as it off-topic. In fact, I just voted for re-opening it and I agree the link I provided above doesn't describe the `@hook:eventName` syntax, which is not documented anywhere on Vue website.

Answer (score 3):

for some reason, thats not in the official docs.

you can use the vue instance life cycle hooks as events from the child to the parent,

something like: `@hook:destroyed="changeMsg()"`

i saw it [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-event-hooks/)

and here is a simple example:

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: '<h1>im the child component</h1>'
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      msg:'not destroyed yet...',
      isDead:false
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(this.die,4000)
  },
  methods:{
    changeMsg(){
      this.msg  = 'the child component is destroyed now';
    },
    die(){
      this.isDead  = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<p><b>msg from parent:</b> {{msg}}</p>
  <greeting v-if="!isDead" @hook:destroyed="changeMsg()"></greeting>
</div>
```